# Сортировка List по нескольким полям

Tags: c#

В `List<>` хранятся объекты, которые необходимо отсортировать по нескольким полям одновременно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Через `LINQ` запись будет выглядеть даже проще:

```
IEnumerable<T> result = nonSorted.OrderBy(x => x.value1).ThenBy(x => x.value2);
```

---

Если хотите избежать ленивых вычислений, то можно сразу спроектировать результат в `IList<>`:

```
IList<T> result = nonSorted.OrderBy(x => x.value1).ThenBy(x => x.value2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ordering Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#thenBySimple) должно помочь

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };//c List<T> тоже будет работать

    var sortedDigits =
        from d in digits
        orderby d.Length, d
        select d;
```

```
one
six
two
five
four
nine
zero
eight
seven
three
```

Answer (score 1):

Лист уже сам по себе все умеет:

> static int comparison< T >(T a, T b){/*сравнение по нужному алгоритму*/}

....

> list.Sort(comparison);

либо если можно изменять класс, экземпляры которого лежат в листе, то:

> ```
>    private class MyClass:IComparable< MyClass >
>     {
>         public int CompareTo(MyClass other){
>             // сравнение по нужному алгоритму
>         }
>     }
> ```

и будет достаточно вызвать метод Sort без параметров.

Comment: *Ну если есть мощнейшее средство для работы с коллекциями (`LINQ`), зачем же его избегать.* Тем более, что оно работает применительно к интерфейсу `IEnumerable<T>`, а не к какой-то конкретной реализации этого интерфейса.

Comment: ну я спорить не буду, но предположим, что мы пишем под 2.0 - как быть?
в общем я считаю, такие вещи знать все равно не лишне.

Comment: Ладно, согласен. Кстати говоря, под 2.0 есть [**LinqBridge.**][1]

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

Comment: хорошая ссылка, спасибо - не думал что можно и так схитрить :)
ну раз уж у нас разговор на тему линка, не подскажите, насколько хуже производительность линка по сравнению с обходами по коллекциям ручками?

Comment: ну удобно - если привыкнуть.. я не пишу - мне удобнее написать какой-нибудь форыч :) интересно просто насколько эффективнее может оказаться линк по скорости написания/оптимальности

зы. ссылка не работает

Comment: Ну есть бенчмарки вроде [этого,][1] но вообще глобальное правило сохраняется - используй то, что удобно, оптимизируй то, что медленно. На LINQ'e удобно писать код, а те случаи, когда ты случайно пишешь код, работающий за O(n^4), уже оптимизируются в ходе профайлинга.

----------

Судя по этому бенчмарку, `LINQ` как раз проигрывает `foreach'у`, видимо, плата за абстракцию.

[1]: http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно отсортировать исходный список, используйте Comparison, который предлагает Дмитрий Ложкин. Если Вам нужно получить новый отсортированный список на основе старого, то используйте Linq.