# Сортировка по нескольким столбцам datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Как сделать сортировку по двум столбцам в datagridview? Источник данных - txt файл. Всего 5 столбцов  из них нужно по двум сделать сортировку.

Например: `А0, А450, Y56200, Y9600` и тд.

Сами данные представлены в виде строковых значений.
Понимаю, как можно по одному столбцу сделать сортировку, но по двум ума не приложу. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Опишите класс с 5 полями и проинициализируйте его. Полученную коллекцию можно отсортировать с помощью LINQ to Object, используя методы OrderBy, OrderByDescemding, ThenBy и ThenByDescending

Comment: Напишите что храниться в файле и по каким полям надо сортировать. Я напишу код

Comment: X56820 Y47283 W84742 H373 A450; сортировка должна проводиться по полям Y и А.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47286/Сортировка-list-по-нескольким-полям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас есть модель, которая описывает структуру одной записи в файле:

```
    class Example
    {
        public string X { get; set; }
        public string Y { get; set; }
        public string W { get; set; }
        public string H { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
    }
```

И файл уже прочитан и записан в коллекцию, например

```
IEnumerable<Example> exampleCollection
```

Тогда можно сортировать коллекцию, используя LINQ to Object:

1. **OrderBy** - сортирует элементы последовательности в порядке возрастания
2. **OrderByDescending** - сортирует элементы последовательности в порядке убывания
3. **ThenBy** - выполняет дополнительное упорядочивание элементов последовательности в порядке возрастания
4. **ThenByDescending** - выполняет дополнительное упорядочивание элементов последовательности в порядке убывания

В вашем случае, для сортировки по двум столбцам используем:

```
exampleCollection = exampleCollection.OrderBy(e => e.Y).ThenBy(e => e.A);
```

**Внимание!** Этот запрос использует отложенное выполнение.

**Что делает этот код?**

Этот код выполняет сортировку коллекции по возрастанию по полю Y, если поля Y равны, то выполняется дополнительная сортировка по полю A, так же по возрастанию.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: Хм, а у меня вопрос. Могу ли я описать структуру записи в datagridview?

Comment: @Jeron, Не работаю с Window Forms, поэтому ничего конкретно сказать не могу. Вероятнее всего, что структура записи в DataGridView представлена коллекцией