# Сортировка по полю

Tags: c#

Есть класс `Contact` с полями `public int number` и `public string name` Я хочу сортировать по `name`

```
class Contact
{
   public int number;
   public string name;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 250;
        string t = "";

        Contact[] ob = new Contact[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ob[i] = new Contact();
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка по нескольким столбцам datagridview](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613742/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc-datagridview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вашего случая (массив) можно, например, так:

```
Array.Sort(contacts, (c1, c2) => c1.name.CompareTo(c2.name));
```

Answer (score 2):

Как один из вариантов:

```
ob = ob.OrderBy(c => c.name).ToArray();
```